# In levelplot (RasterVis), what by default does the graph show on each axis?

Tags: r, raster, levelplot

I'm using the `levelplot` function in the `RasterVis` package to plot one raster. I use the following code on my GeoTiff:

```
require(raster)
require(rasterVis)
data <- raster("mytiff.tif")
levelplot(data, layers=1, par.settings=RdBuTheme)
```

What, by default, do the graphs presented in the margins show? Is it the mean for each column/row or the median or a cumulative count or something else?

I can't find this in the help information, so any enlightenment would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These graphics are the row and column summaries of the
`RasterLayer`. The summary is computed with the function defined by
`FUN.margin` (which uses `mean` as default value).

Let's illustrate it with an example:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)

levelplot(r)
```

[image: levelplot]

The graphics shown in the margins can be produced with the `zonal`
function.  With `init` we create two `RasterLayer` with the rows and
cols numbers to define the zones to be summarized.

```
rows <- init(r, v='row')
cols <- init(r, v='col')

rAvg <- zonal(r, rows, fun='mean')
cAvg <- zonal(r, cols, fun='mean')
```

The result is the same:

```
plot(rAvg, type='l')
```

[image: row average]

```
plot(cAvg, type='l')
```

[image: column average]

Comment: Is it possible to re-arrange the marginal plots? Instead of top/right, left/bottom?

Comment: I am afraid this option is not implemented in rasterVis.